# Is it safe to use Spring Cloud Dataflow Local Server on production?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

We are looking into implementing spring cloud data flow in a local system environment to process streams and task jobs for day to day transactions. Without using PCF, Kubernetes, YARN or Mesos, we are thinking of using the local server for orchestration. We find that it is recommended to be used for development only. Will there be any issues/problems using it in production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The local-server is a simple Spring Boot app and it is strongly only recommended for development needs. There's no reliability, fault-tolerance, or HA capabilities available if you're relying on local-server.

You might want to consider one of the Spring Cloud Data Flow platform implementations for reliable production coverage. There's community implementations of [Openshift](https://github.com/donovanmuller/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-openshift) and [Nomad](https://github.com/donovanmuller/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-nomad) available, too.